# wp8 D3D11, when interrupt, I can't release SRV which is current using

Tags: windows-phone-8, direct3d11

I create the project for winphone8 use the template Direct3D & XAML, when I pressed win button, it call OnNavigatedFrom for interrupt, here I release all the D3D11 ID3D11ShaderResourceView* and hope to recreate them when back to my game.
I print log of app memory when release every SRV. I found out that the memory is acturally released when I call Release() for a SRV, except the SRVs which are current using. So the momery is leaked.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, and memory is not actually leaked because the reference is still held in a well-defined way by the graphics pipeline. To release the memory, set the slot that the shader resource view is bound to to NULL.